# How to return element object from a function that return an object in javascript?

Tags: javascript

**This is only for learning purpose not for making something else.**

In this code below I need some fixing. When I call the superUser('elm') it should return all the specific elements that were given instead of returning whole the objects. Similar to jQuery, (just for learning purpose).

So, It should work like jQuery.

When I called the only `superUser('elm')` It should return what jQuery return I mean all the elements. Again If I call `superUser('elm').on('click', function)` it should also work in this case.

```js
!(function (global, factory) {

    if (typeof factory === 'function')
        global.superUser = factory();

}(typeof window !== undefined ? window : this, function () {


    /**
     * 
     * @object
     * Initilize the main object
     * 
     */
    let superUser_fn = {};

    /**
     * @targeted_element
     * this will give an elm
     * 
     */

    let elm = '';


    /**
     * @superUser
     * the main function for the project
     * 
     */
    const superUser = function (element) {
        elm = document.querySelectorAll(element);

        return superUser_fn;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @handling_event
     * This will return an event listener if exist else
     * it will attach a event for the client
     * 
     * @arguments
     * @event = it will give a event for action
     * @callback = a callback function
     * 
     */

    superUser_fn['on'] = function (event, callback) {
        if (elm !== null)
            if (elm.addEventListener)
                elm.addEventListener(event, callback);
            else if (elm.attachEvent)
            elm.attachEvent(event, callback);
    }



    /**
     * 
     * @return
     * return the full object what ever we work in
     */
    return superUser;

}));


console.log(superUser('h1'));
```

Comment: do you need key-value pairs of the object returned depending on provided arguments?

Comment: @EugenSunic What he needs already declared in this article. When he call the superUser('elm') then it should return all the dom objects, what jQuery did.

Answer (score 1):

```
const superUser = function (element) {
    elm = document.querySelectorAll(element);
    elm.on = superUser_fn['on'];
    return elm;
}

/**
 * 
 * @handling_event
 * This will return an event listener if exist else
 * it will attach a event for the client
 * 
 * @arguments
 * @event = it will give a event for action
 * @callback = a callback function
 * 
 */

superUser_fn['on'] = function (event, callback) {
    const handler = () => callback(elm)
    if (elm !== null)
        if (elm.addEventListener)
            elm.addEventListener(event, handler);
        else if (elm.attachEvent)
        elm.attachEvent(event, handler);
```

Not sure if I got your intention..but.. it seems close enough for me to share